# Не работает hover при наведении на меню на телефонах и планшетах

Tags: drupal

Здравствуйте на Drupal сайте стоит модуль [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu%5C)

На компьютере при наведении на меню всплывает окно, а на телефоне и планшете не работает, я так понимаю hover не работает на touch-устройствах, как это исправить?

Comment: Вот неплохая статья на эту тему: http://www.maximastudio.ru/blog/238-hover-effekt-dlya-sensornykh-touch-tach-ustroystv

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать перейти на модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish - там есть работа с сенсорными устройствами.